# Display a random background image using only html and css

Tags: html, css

I know that there are ways to radomize background images using php and javascript; I am not looking for such a solution. Is there was a way to randomly show one of three background images using only css and html?

I have no restrictions that are preventing me from using php and javascript; this is mostly out of curiousity.

Comment: As far I know, this is not possible. [This](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/randomize-background-image/) may help you.

Comment: Would you be amenable to an answer using SASS, SCSS, or LESS?

Comment: CSS and HTML aren't programming languages and don't have random number generation built in (yet?). The closest you could get would be using a preprocessed language like SASS, but in that case those random numbers are generated once when processed, but not when the page is reloaded or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to do this in standard CSS.

The only way to do this is either server side (e.g. php) or with javascript on the front-end.